# Convert to PDF if Sheet's name is on list

Tags: excel, vba

I found multiple examples for checking if a certain Sheet matches with one Name, but I need to check if one of the sheets in my Workbook (at least 70 Sheets) is a Item on a List ( at least 30 Names).

If a Sheet matches, convert to PDF, resume.

```vb
Sub PDFAlle2()
Dim w, ws As Worksheet
wsListe As String
Dim fName As String
wsListe = Sheets("Liste").Range("B3:B5")
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = wsListe Then '<-- this obviously doesn't work
        With ActiveSheet
           fName = .Range("E2").Value & "Ausdruck"
           .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
             "C:\PDFTest\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=False
         End With
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Export Worksheets From a List to PDF

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PDFAlle2()
    
    'Source
    Const sName As String = "Liste"
    Const sCol As String = "B"
    Const sfRow As Long = 3
    ' Destination
    Const diFolderPath As String = "C:\PDFTest\"
    Const dPDFNameAddress As String = "E2"
    Const dPDFSuffix As String = "Ausdruck"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the range ('srg') containing the worksheet names.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then
        Err.Raise 91, , "No data in column '" & sCol & "' starting from row " _
            & sfRow & "."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(sfRow, sCol), sws.Cells(slRow, sCol))
    
    ' Check the destination folderpath.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = diFolderPath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 76, , "The path '" & dFolderPath & "' was not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dName As String
    Dim dCount As Long
    
    ' Loop through the cells with the names instead of the worksheets.
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        ' Attempt to reference the worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Worksheets(CStr(sCell.Value))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet exists
            dName = vbNullString
            dName = CStr(dws.Range(dPDFNameAddress).Value)
            If Len(dName) > 0 Then ' cell is not empty
                dName = dName & dPDFSuffix
                dws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                    Filename:=dFolderPath & dName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=False
                dCount = dCount + 1 ' counter for the message
            'Else ' cell is empty
            End If
            Set dws = Nothing
        'Else ' worksheet doesn't exist
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    MsgBox "Exported " & dCount & " worksheet(s).", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two Lists:

1. list of sheets
2. list of filenames in the column.

Your current code loops through list of Sheets only...

Statement `With ActiveSheet` inside the loop is wrong, - as code not activating any other sheets and it is not recommended to activate them to make code run faster. From this mistake, next one accured.

`fName = .Range("E2").Value & "Ausdruck` statement is incorrect,
it should specify the sheet, `fName = ws.Range("E2").Value & "Ausdruck`.

Also, `wsListe` in your code was used as range, but tried to be dimmed to a string.

Example:

```
Sub PDFAlle2()

Dim w, ws As Worksheet
Dim wsListe As Range 'Range not string
Dim fName As String

Set wsListe = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Liste").Range("B3:B5")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each v In wsListe
        If ws.Name = v Then
        fName = ws.Range("E2").Value & "Ausdruck" 'ws.Range not just .Range as code not sets any other sheet active, main sheet with file names stays active.
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\PDFTest\" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
    Next v
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the explantations, but if I try to run the code runtime error 1004 nothing could be found to print occurs.

Comment: Put cursor in the Macros code, and press F8, so you can activate each row step by step and check which part causes the error.

Comment: also check if any PDF files are open with the same name which may be generated by code.
Also, if E2 cell will be empty, - you will get error

Comment: Complete forgot, my code runs ok, if you run it from sheet "Liste"

Comment: Declaring variables in one line is done in the following way: `Dim w As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet`. But you aren't using `w` anyway. You could benefit from using `Option Explicit` at the top of each module which would have alerted you that `v` is not declared, which is also an inappropriate name for a cell (range). So you could e.g. do `Dim vCell As Range` and later do `For Each vCell in wsListe.Cells`. When you are looping through the sheets collection using a worksheet variable, if the workbook contains a chart, an error will occur. Rather use `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, after deleting and recreating the folder everything runs smoothly and I learned a lot.